# SPFile file > issues adding a file

Tags: development

My file is in the solution (Files\customer invoice.xls) and this is how I am referencing it in the code. but in debug it shows c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Files\customer invoice.xls'.

how should I reference it?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any additional code my first guess is that you have mixed up System.IO.File and Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.

Please add your code as well to the question, that would help, a lot!

Comment: How do I copy a file from a site collection list to another list in a web (under the same sc)? (oh using object model)

Comment: Robert G - use SPFile.CopyTo() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471128.aspx) - but I'd recommend you ask that in a new question as the answer is very specific and different to the problem described in this question.